# Possible to overwrite {% block content %} by a custom block that resides inside it?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

If I have this in my "main" (or project's) base.html:

```
{% block content %}
  I'm inside block content.
   {% block main_sidebar %}
     I'm inside my sidebar now.
   {% endblock main_sidebar %}  
{% endblock %}
```

And, in the app's base.html (this base extends off the main base.html), I have this:

```
 {% block main_sidebar %}
    I want to change this.
 {% endblock main_sidebar %}
```

The output doesn't change in my app's base.html for the main sidebar.

If I change `{% block content %}` to a custom name, then it works. I guess `{% block content %}` has special privileges as a block name and so can't be overwritten in a case like the one above?

Comment: No, there's no special-casing in block names (or anywhere, really: it's against the zen of Python). Have you perhaps got another block somewhere called "content"?

Comment: Hi Daniel - yup that was it. My project's base is extended in my app's base which extends another template which also included a block content name. Thanks for your help!